# Batch rename spaces in filenames to underscore

Tags: linux, sh, xargs

I have a directory called `windows` which contains files with names containing spaces. I want to replace the spaces in file names with underscores `_`. I need to correct all file names in the `windows` directory.

**Constraints:**

- I'm allowed only one command.
- Solutions must not contain control structures (if, while, for, etc.).
- Solutions must not contain command substitutions $(...), special characters like ;, &, &&, ${}, ||, etc.

I'm looking for a solution that respects all the constraints mentioned above. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use the `rename` command?

Comment: And it has `-exec`, so you don't need `xargs`. `xargs` won't even work when the filenames have spaces, since it will treat them as separate arguments (unless you use `-print0` and `xargs -0`).

Comment: no I can only use what's provided in a basic Ubuntu distribution

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for **practical**, answerable questions (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Do you have a practical reason for these restrictions or are they part of a classroom exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `-regex` condition to match the filenames, instead of piping to `grep`.

Use the built-in `-exec` operator to execute the `bash` command to perform the filename substitution and `mv` command.

Use `sed` in a command substitution to perform the space replacements.

```
find windows -type f -regex '/.{4} .{4} .{4}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,3}$' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(sed "s/ /_/g" <<<"$1")"' {} {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you but the command use ${1// /_} and I'm not allowed to use it

Comment: I've changed it to use `sed` in a command substitution.

Comment: I'm unsure why but that regex pattern did not locate the intended files. I modified it and it works 

```sh
find windows -type f -regex '.*/[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+-[0-9]+' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(sed "s/ /_/g" <<<"$1")"' {} {} \;
```
But the constraints in this assignment are really tedious, I'm not allowed to use command substitution so this command would not be accepted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that command substitution isn't allowed.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? Was there any hint in the lesson about what you ARE supposed to use? Because I can't think of a way without command substitution or parameter expansion operators.

Comment: What's the point of this assignment when they prohibit all the usual ways to do replacements?

Comment: Yes, it's an assignment, and I don't see the point either. The instructions insist on using xargs and sh, but both commands' functionalities frequently overlap with what I'm not allowed to use. 
I asked my teacher about this, and he said that my solution doesn't have to be generic because all the files follow a specific pattern: four letters, a space, four letters, a space, four letters, a hyphen, and one to three digits.

Comment: From your description, it sounds very much like he is pushing you to use `rename` from the `util-linux` package that is installed on just about every distribution out there. Some provide `perl-rename` as `rename` (which is much much more capable). However for a fixed pattern, then `rename` from `util-linux` will do. Otherwise, without command substitution and without use of `$()` from an advanced shell, your options are limited and involve more than 1 command. `sed` or `tr` in a command substitution with `mv` would be the normal route absent `rename`.

Comment: @sauvy `xargs` and `sh` allow you to pass the filenames to a script, but they don't provide any way to do the character replacement.

Comment: And scrap `rename` from `util-linux`, it will NOT handle the pattern you have without looping to remove one space at a time -- not likely what your teacher has in mind.

Comment: You can use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) instead of the command substitution; `"${1// /_/}"` (though apparently that's prohibited as well).

Comment: @tripleee That was my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

A comment clarifies that the filenames of interest follow a rigid naming convention:

> all the files follow a specific pattern: four letters, a space, four letters, a space, four letters, a hyphen, and one to three digits

So:

```
find windows -maxdepth 1 -type f |
grep -iE '^windows([/ ][a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9]{1,3}$' |
xargs -r -n3 sh -c 'mv "$*" $1_$2_$3' --
```

Another comment states:

> I can only use what's provided in a basic Ubuntu distribution

coreutils (`mv`), findutils (`find`/`xargs`), grep (`grep`) and dash (`sh`) are all required packages in Ubuntu.

`base64` is also required, allowing:

```
echo ZmluZCB3aW5kb3dzIC1tYXhkZXB0aCAxIC10eXBlIGZ8Z3JlcCAtaUUgJ153aW5kb3dzKFsvIF1bYS16XXs0fSl7M30tWzAtOV17MSwzfSQnfHhhcmdzIC1yIC1uMyBzaCAtYyAnZWNobyBtdiAiJCoiICQxXyQyXyQzJyAt | base64 -d | sh
```

Comment: The base64 trick is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
find windows -depth -exec rename -e 's/ /_/g' {} +
```

`-depth` if needed if any of the file names with spaces are directories.

This `rename` is provided as `perl-rename` on some distros.

Same idea, just without `rename`:

```bash
find windows -depth -exec perl -e'
   use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
   for ( @ARGV ) {
      my $old = $_;
      my ( $f, $d ) = fileparse( $_ );
      $f =~ s/ /_/g;
      my $new = $d.$f;
      rename( $old, $new ) if $new ne $old;
   }
' {} +
```

Same idea, but moves the loop from `perl` to `find` so you don't see `for` (but it does introduce a shell special character, `\`):

```bash
find windows -depth -exec perl -e'
   use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
   my $old = $ARGV[0];
   my ( $f, $d ) = fileparse( $old );
   $f =~ s/ /_/g;
   my $new = $d.$f;
   rename( $old, $new ) if $new ne $old;
' {} \;
```

Comment: your perl has lots of `;` which is apparently verboten. also`perl` and Perl's `rename` are both optional packages so not part of the ubuntu base system (which a comment states is all that can be used)

Comment: @jhnc, Re "*which is apparently verboten.*", No, the `;` is not a shell special character here. (All the other solutions use `|`, which is. `'` and spaces are also special, but they're unavoidable.)